# Debugging a python requests module 400 error

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm doing a post request using python and confluence REST API in order to update confluence pages via a script.
I ran into a problem which caused me to receive a 400 error in response to a 
`requests.put(url, data = jsonData, auth = (username, passwd), headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'})`

I spent some time on this to discover that the reason for it was me not supplying an incremented version when updating the content. I have managed to make my script work, but that is not the point of this question.

During my attempts to make this work, I swapped from requests to an http.client connection. Using this module, I get a lot more information regarding my error:

`b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Must supply an incremented version when updating Content. No version supplied.","reason":"Bad Request"}'`

Is there a way for me to get the same feedback information while using requests? I've turned on logging, but this kind of info is never shown.

Comment: What does requests.json() output?

Comment: Exactly what I needed :) I tried several options but was not aware of this one. Thank you!

Comment: To get more logs from the requests module assign the request output to a var and print the `.text` attribute, e.g. `var = requests.put(url, data = jsonData, auth = (username, passwd), headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}) \\ print(var.text)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for

```py
requests.json()
```

It outputs everything the requests item returns, as a dictionary.